# React waiting for setState to finish then call a function

Tags: reactjs, async-await

When my code is ran it uses old values for interest since its async how to make calcMoney wait for the state to be updated? Thanks in advance

UPDATE THIS IS THE ENTIRE CODE IT IS MOST LIKELY REALLY MESSED UP SINCE I AM JUST STARTING REACT AND WHAT EXACTLY SHOULD BELONG INSIDE THE RENDER AND WHAT SHOULD BE ELSEWHERE IS YET A MYSTERY TO ME

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function InputForm() {
  const [investinit, setInvestinit] = useState("");
  const [deposit, setDeposit] = useState("");
  const [interest, setInterest] = useState("");

  function changeInit(e) {
    setInvestinit(parseInt(e.target.value));
    console.log(e);
    calcMoney();
  }

  function changeDeposit(e) {
    if (e.target.value == "") {
      e.target.value = 0;
    }
    setDeposit(parseInt(e.target.value));
    calcMoney();
  }

  function changeInterest(e) {
    setInterest(parseFloat(e.target.value), () =>
    console.log(e);
  }

  function calcMoney() {
    var bigArr = [
      { totalAmount: investinit, tottalYield: 0, id: 0, totalMonthly: deposit },
    ];
    var monthlyInterest = interest / 1200 + 1;

    for (var i = 1; i < 13; i = i + 1) {
      var newTotal =
        investinit * Math.pow(monthlyInterest, i) +
        deposit * ((Math.pow(monthlyInterest, i) - 1) / (monthlyInterest - 1));
      var totalMonthly = deposit * i;
      var gain = newTotal - (investinit + totalMonthly);

      bigArr.push({
        totalAmount: newTotal,
        id: i,
        tottalYield: gain,
        totalMonthly: totalMonthly,
      });
      console.log(bigArr);
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="wrapper">
      <div className="form-wrap">
        <form>
          <div className="form-body">
            <div className="form-item">
              <label>Investment Amount $</label>
              <input
                type="number"
                onChange={changeInit}
                value={investinit}
                placeholder="Investment Amount (required)"
                min="0"
                step="100"
                required
              />
            </div>
            <div className="form-item">
              <label>Monthly investment $</label>
              <input
                type="number"
                onChange={changeDeposit}
                value={deposit}
                placeholder="Monthly Deposit (optional)"
                min="0"
                step="100"
              />
            </div>
            <div className="form-item">
              <label>Annual interest %</label>
              <input
                type="number"
                onChange={changeInterest}
                value={interest}
                placeholder="Annual interest (required)"
                min="0"
                step="0.1"
                required
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
export { InputForm };
```

Comment: it is likely that calcMoney should be called in the render function and directly access 'insterest' from the state. Can you share a bit more of your code to see the whole picture ?

Comment: I posted the entire code

Comment: the 'calcMoney' function does nothing except a console.log ?

Comment: It does it is created a bit lower i just needed to know at that point the event

Comment: then go for the second answer from Phobos with 'useEffect' and remove the calcMoney call from the changeDeposit function and it should be ok :)

Comment: Thank you so much the effect method worked <3.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Fixed using the inbuilt React Context, passing the calculator the values as props and wrapping all the componenents needing the data with a value provider.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Your answer doesn't answer your original question so shouldn't really be marked as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

the setState function takes an optional callback parameter that can be used to make updates after the state has changed:

```
setInterest(parseFloat(e.target.value), () => {
   calcMoney();
}
```

Alternatively, you could use useEffect and watch the value of 'interest' and perform the calculation whenever it changes.

```
useEffect(() => {
  calcMoney();
}, [interest]);
```

Comment: Tried it with the callback and got this  Warning: State updates from the useState() and useReducer() Hooks don't support the second callback argument. To execute a side effect after rendering, declare it in the component body with useEffect().

Comment: Then use the useEffect method, should achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

There are three options for this problem that you can find useful:

1. The First thing you can do is to use the **promise** with **await** function in the function itself. It can cause a wait until the async function gets the data and then update the state with setState.
2. The second approach would be to use callback functions. To do so you can use it inside your async function or also you may change your setState function to accept the callback function. In a way that you run your setState after the fetching (async) to be finished.
3. Is to utilize the useEffect to wait for the output of the async function and when it changes, useEffect would run a function or call other functions.

> Note that Fetch is already returning a promise, so it may be more
> sound to use that.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/new-project-z7mdp  This is the codesandbox with my solution the problem is that everything gets rendered with the value that was in the previous step try it out you will know what I mean, Is there an easy solution for that? I

Comment: @JanDoležel I have made some changes (forked) to your code that is working correctly. The code may not be what you exactly need but you can get how this thing works. Do not forget to upvote my comment or as the best answer: [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/new-project-forked-zjjuv?file=/src/Modules/InputForm.js)